# How to merge two rows having same values into single row in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I am having a table called 'data' in that the values will be like following,

```
ID  NAME    DOB LOCATION
1   bob 08/10/1985  NEW JERSEY
1   bob 15/09/1987  NEW YORK
2   John    08/10/1985  NORTH CAROLINA
2   John    26/11/1990  OKLAHOMA
```

For example 
I want output like,

```
ID  NAME    No.of.Days                 
1   bob difference of two given dates in days   
2   John    difference of two given dates in days
```

Please help me to form a python code to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will be only two dates in a for a given ID then below works!

```
df.groupby(['ID','NAME'])['DOB'].apply(lambda x: abs(pd.to_datetime(list(x)[0]) - pd.to_datetime(list(x)[1]))).reset_index(name='No.Of.Days')
```

**Output**

```
   ID   NAME  No.Of.Days
0    1    bob   766 days
1    2   John  1934 days
```

you can use [np.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) also

```
df.groupby(['ID','NAME'])['DOB'].apply(lambda x: np.diff(list(x))[0]).reset_index(name='No.Of.Days')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but it didnt work,.. I got following error: Attribute error:'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'strip;..

Comment: apply the code on the posted df..and then please post the complete df since the code works only on case like above..for generic i need more data

Comment: Shall I use the same logic without grouping id and name ..? If I just need a difference of two dates..

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to convert `Date` column into `date` format. Lets suppose you are reading from `.csv` then read your `.csv` file as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', parse_dates = ['DOB'])
```

otherwise, convert your existing dataframe column into `date` format as follows.

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])
```

now, you can perform the usual numeric operations.

```
df.groupby(['ID','NAME'])['DOB'].apply(lambda x: abs(pd.to_datetime(list(x)[0]) - pd.to_datetime(list(x)[1]))).reset_index(name='No.Of.Days')
```